# Solve this Fourier Transform

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals, fourier-transform, characteristic-functions, integral-transforms

I want to solve the following integral:

$$
f_{X}(x)
 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
      \exp\left( \frac{-j (N-1) \alpha t - (N+1) \alpha \beta t^{2}}
                      {(1- j \beta t) (1+j \beta t)} \right)
      \frac{e^{jxt}}{(1-j\beta t)^{N}(1+j \beta t)^{N}}  dt
$$

where $\alpha , \beta \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$ and $N \in \mathbb{Z}_{++}$ and $j = \sqrt{-1}$.

However, I am not sure how to deal with the $t^{2}$ in the exponential.

It seems to suggest completing the square, but perhaps I am failing in my algebra, because I can't get anywhere that way.

---

**The completing the square idea:**

We expand the integrand as follows:

$$
\exp\left(\frac{-j(N-1) \alpha t}{(1- j \beta t) (1 + j \beta t)}\right)
\exp\left(\frac{-(N+1) \alpha \beta t^{2}}{(1- j \beta t) (1 + j \beta t)}\right)
\exp\left(\frac{jxt(1- j \beta t) (1 + j \beta t)}{(1- j \beta t) (1 + j \beta t)}\right)$$

Then I try to eliminate all the imaginary numbers except for the coefficients of $xt$, so we can take a Fourier transform of a rational function and use the resideu thm. However, this is where I get stuck....perhaps this is not the right approach.

Anyway...Mathematica seems to have failed to find an answer.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can simplify somewhat with $(1-j\beta t)^k(1+j\beta t)^k=(1+\beta^2t^2)^k$ for $k\in\{1,\,N\}$, but you'll need more than that fact to solve the problem.

Comment: @J.G. Cool, anything helps! This might trigger my brain somehow...